# SQL join two select syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm working with SQLite and i need to do two select statement and join them by a column. Here is the code that i'm actually trying to get working:

The tables are like this:

**msgstore.db**
messages: | _id | key_remote_jid |

**wa.db**
wa_contacts: | _id | jid | a lot of columns

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'path\msgstore.db' As db1;
ATTACH DATABASE 'path\wa.db' As db2;
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT db1.messages.remote_resource FROM db1.messages WHERE key_remote_jid = "somevalue" AND remote_resource IS NOT Null) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT db2.wa_contacts.* FROM db2.wa_contacts) AS T2
ON T1.remote_resource = T2.jid
```

This code says that there is a syntax error near "*", but i can't find out what is it.
Need some advice on how to fix this.

Comment: Try changing `SELECT T1.*, T2.*` to `SELECT *` and check.

Comment: Also try changing db2.wa_contacts.* to * :)

Comment: I tried both solutions and it worked. Seems that the statement that Himanshu pointed out was the one raising the syntax error. thank you both!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to document @Himanshu answer:

As you may find in [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), [result column](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#result-column) may use `table.*` or `*`, but not `database.table.*`.

So `SELECT db2.wa_contacts.*` must revert to `SELECT db2.wa_contacts.*`.

By the way, whole `(SELECT db2.wa_contacts.* FROM db2.wa_contacts)` may be simply refered as `db2.wa_contacts`.